# Source code structure: deploying Go with Subpackages

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When there is just one go repository and it imports only public dependencies, deploying to (for example, a Docker container on AWS) is extremely straightforward.

However, I have a question about how to use subpackages with go.

Suppose we have a monorepo with 3 packages.

```
/src
- /appA
- /appB
- /someSharedDep
```

How are deployments typically built so that you deploy appA and someSharedDep to one server and appB and someSharedDep on another server?

I imagine there needs to be some creative employments of our friend the GOPATH, but some help on the topic would be appreciated.

Bonus points if we're talking about an elastic beanstalk deployment.

### Suspicions

I have some thoughts on how to approach the problem now (and I'll add more or submit an answer if this becomes more complete).

1. Use vendoring, this means you have the source code of all your dependencies checked into your own repo. It doesn't sound good (esp. if you're used to NodeJS) but it works.
2. Now that you use vendoring, vendor your own submodules into the `./vendor` folder in the application. Yes you will have copies of the same code in two places but whatever.
3. Create automated scripts to help manage some of these things. I'm still looking for tools that make vendoring more convenient.

Some problems I still face:

1. When vendoring, sometimes the dependency has files that have a main() function or declare `package main`, usually in an `./example` subfolder. These have to be removed manually. I don't like editing the working source of someone else's project though!

Comment: After building the binary, the dependencies matter not.  Just deploy the two binaries appA and appB.

Comment: Is someSharedDep a different app or a library?

Comment: @SnoProblem I imagine someSharedDep to be some shared functions or constants between appA and appB. It might also be a shared database helper that defines tables that both appA and appB, for example.

Comment: @BravadaZadada I'm not quite sure how to deploy binaries to services like AWS through docker, is that something you can speak more to?

Comment: Once appA and appB are compiled to executables, they have everything they need from someSharedDep included in that binary.  Then, it can be deployed as any other executable:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_go.html

Comment: Thanks @BravadaZadada it took some time to get up to speed on exactly what Docker is and some of go's build processes; is having an image with just a binary (that comes from a previous build step) an anti-pattern in any way? Would you do the build steps in a separate docker container too (to keep things the same)?